# Cannot figgure out PSQL where issue in complicated clause

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a native query

```
        "SELECT *, point(?2, ?1) <@> point(lng,lat) as distance FROM workers " +
                " LEFT JOIN availabilities on availabilities.worker_id = workers.id " +
                " WHERE workers.category_id = ?3 " +
                " WHERE worker_availability.time = ?4 ORDER BY distance ASC",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
```

The error I keep getting is

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
```

Comment: You can only have a **single** WHERE clause in a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "WHERE" 2 times. You must change this:

```
" WHERE worker_availability.time = ?4 ORDER BY distance ASC",
```

to this:

```
" AND worker_availability.time = ?4 ORDER BY distance ASC",
```